# How do you get the user ID of a tagged user with the Telegram Bot API?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

If someone sends the command `/command @user` for example, how can I get the user ID for that tagged / mentioned user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. [`MessageEntity`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#messageentity) objects of type `mention` don't have the `MessageEntity.user` field and you can't resolve the username to the user id via [`get_chat`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchat) either.